# C++ Error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::swap(std::vector<int>)'

Tags: c++, vector, swap

I was reading a blog about std::vector. See the **Swapping contents** section in this [website](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm).

---

Basically, it says a common application of `swap()` method is forcing a vector to release the memory it holds. But after I ran the code below, I got the error `Error: no matching function for call to 'std::vector<int>::swap(std::vector<int>)'|`. Where has gone wrong?

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main( )
{
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.push_back(1); v.push_back(2);
    v.clear();
    v.swap(std::vector<int>(v));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The parameter type of [std::vector::swap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/swap) is a non-const lvalue reference (i.e. `vector&`). But `std::vector<int>(v)` is a temporary object, which can't be bound to non-const reference.

That means when use "swap trick", you should put the temporary on the left side:

```
std::vector<int>(v).swap(v);
```

---

<sup>Since C++11 you could use [std::vector::shrink_to_fit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit) for requesting the removal of unused capacity; note this is a non-binding request, the effect depends on implementation.</sup>

Comment: Seems the blog has this mistake. One follow-up question, the blog says the  temporary vector is created by using the copy constructor, but I think `std::vector<int>(v)` is just a recast of `v` like we can cast an array into a `std::vector` and cast a float to a double although the type is the same before and after the cast (seems odd). I wonder am I right?

Comment: @Nicholas Yes, for `std::vector<int>(v)` a temporary `vector` needs to be constructed, the copy ctor will be used for it. When you use an array to construct vector, the approriate ctor will be used to construct the vector. Yes this is cast, in essence the approriate constructor will be invoked to construct a `std::vector`.

Comment: No, you should NOT use the copy constructor. That is a waste of memory, especially if the original vector has a large number of item in it.  And it doesn't gain you anything, as you would be swapping a *copy* of the original data back into the original vector, defeating the whole purpose of this exercise. You need to default-construct the temp object that you are going to swap with, eg: `std::vector<int>().swap(v);` This way, the original vector releases ownership of its allocated memory, and the temp vector takes ownership so it gets freed when the temp goes out of scope,

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think OP only wants to release capacity?

Comment: @songyuanyao: That is what I am saying. If you use a **copy-constructed** temp vector, it will copy the data, leaving the original data intact, and then the swap will just switch memory pointers. The original vector will end up with the same data it started with, just located at a new memory address. But if you use a **default-constructed** temp vector, the original vector will not have any memory assigned to it anymore, and the temp vector will free the original memory.

Comment: @RemyLebeau But if we do so, `v` will be empty, the elements won't be preserved.

Comment: @songyuanyao: **this is the whole point of this exercise**! "*forcing a vector to release the memory it holds*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau It depends on your request; if you want to clear it, it's fine. If you want to preserve elements, you just can't do this. The point is, if you want to preserve the elements, only release capacity, how to achieve it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126947/discussion-between-remy-lebeau-and-songyuanyao).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector::swap()` does not accept a temporary object as input.  It takes the input object as a **non-const lvalue reference** (so it can modify the input object).  A **non-const lvalue reference** *cannot* bind to a temporary object (only a **const lvalue reference** or an **rvalue reference** can do that), which is why you get the compiler error.

You should also use the *default* constructor and not the *copy* constructor, to ensure that the original `vector` gets swapped with an empty state, and the temporary `vector` assumes ownership of the original allocated memory.

Using your original code, you would need to declare another `vector` variable to swap with:

```
std::vector<int> temp;
v.swap(temp);
```

Otherwise, switch the order of the two objects around, which is the preferred approach:

```
std::vector<int>().swap(v);
```

Comment: Let's say `n=v.capacity();` right after line `v.clear();`, then do you suggest that `std::vector<int>(v).swap(v);`, while switches memory pointers, still have `v` occupying `n` memory? But `std::vector<int>().swap(v);` also resets `v`'s capacity to `x`, where `x` is the number of memory `std::vector<int>()` allocates? And in most case, `x` is expected to be smaller than `n`?

Comment: I tried `std::vector<int>().swap(v); std::cout << v.capacity() << v.size();` and `std::vector<int>(v).swap(v); std::cout << v.capacity() << v.size();`, respectively. But for both I got 00? Seems my previous comment is wrong?

Comment: @Nicholas the copy constructor does not guarantee compactness. It is required only to copy elements, thus `size()` will match the original, but the new `capacity()` will be *at least* `size()` but can be larger. It depends on the implementation

Comment: @Nicholas after `v.clear()`, `v.size()` is 0. It is *likely* that the copy constructor will then not allocate anything since it does not copy anything. So `vector<int>(v).swap(v)` could be equivilent to `vector<int>().swap(v)` in that case, but that is not a guarantee. Which is also why the copy constructor is not a reliable way to compact a non-empty  vector.

Comment: Appreciate your detailed explanation.